# MySQL PDO fetchAll as array with integer index

Tags: php, pdo

I have a table with two columns. Table: `ctgtable` and columns: `id` and `ctg`. Since I am entirely moving from previous **`mysql_*`** functions to `PDO`, I am facing some <strike>foolish</strike> mistakes(or maybe lack of knowledge).

## Question

I want to select the entire table's `ctg` column(a total of at most 20 rows) into an array with integer indexes.

## My Method

The nearest possible solution in my opinion was this:

```
<?php
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, ctg FROM ctgtable");
    $sth->execute();
    /* Fetch all of the values of the second column */
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Is there any other shorter/better alternative for the same result? Or this is the best/only possible method to fetch results.

## Sample Table

```
id      ctg
01     movie
27       tv
64     sports
```

etc.

## Sample Result

```
Array( 1 => "tv",
    2 => "movie",
    3 => "anime",
    4 => "game",
    5 => "telugu"
);
```

The indexing may or may not start from 0. It doesn't matter to me. I tried searching for such a possible question, but none of them seemed relevant to my question.

Comment: Do you plan on using the "id" field from your results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you have is fine. Though if you don't need the ID, why would you need to query it?

```
<?php
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ctg FROM ctgtable");
    $sth->execute();
    /* Fetch all of the values in form of a numeric array */
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY);
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Less constraints on the MySQL leads to less processing time, which eventually leads to better results.

Comment: `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY, 0);` The first column. ^_^

Comment: @GiantofaLannister: Edited. There's no column number in FETCH_ARRAY. But basically, query **only for what you need**, if you don't need the ID, don't query for it. It's as simple as that.

Comment: PDO::FETCH_ARRAY is a non-standard PDO constant. see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

 PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is supported on some systems.

 PDO::FETCH_COLUMN is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do the following

```
   <?php
    //connect to db    

    $array = array();//define array

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ctgtable";    
    $result = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();

   while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
      $id =  $row['id'];
      $ctg = $row['ctg'];        
      $array[$id] = $ctg;        
  }

 print_r($array);
 //close connection
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this method be more-time consuming?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have is alright, you could also call [fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) instead of `fetchAll()`. If you chained calls it would look like this:

```
$entries = $dbh->query("SELECT ctg FROM fruit")->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: This only fetches the first entry of the column. I want all the entries at once.

Comment: Chained calls are not recommended, as it hinders readability and may lead to unexpected results. Also, the solution is wrong.